# How Do I Upload Eclipse Projects to GitHub?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have code in Eclipse that I'd like to upload to GitHub but so far I can't figure out how. It says "create a repository" but that looks more like a folder that holds your projects and I'm not sure how to upload my code to it. Apologies for the seemingly dumb question. Also, how does one delete repositories? Didn't see a way to do that either.

Comment: Does your eclipse project use git as an SCM? If not, you need to start here...

Comment: Learn git first just with a local repository (git init). Then github makes much more sense.

Comment: In case you still need it, in order to delete a repository, open it in github, click on the 'Settings' tab and scroll to the bottom, where you will find the 'Delete repository' option. :)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

While the EGit plugin for Eclipse is a good option, an even better one would be to learn to use git bash -- i.e., git from the command line. It isn't terribly difficult to learn the very basics of git, and it is often very beneficial to understand some basic operations before relying on a GUI to do it for you. But to answer your question:

First things first, download git from http://git-scm.com/. Then go to http://github.com/ and create an account and repository.

On your machine, first you will need to navigate to the project folder using git bash. When you get there you do:

```
git init
```

which initiates a new git repository in that directory.

When you've done that, you need to register that new repo with a remote (where you'll upload -- push -- your files to), which in this case will be github. This assumes you have already created a github repository. You'll get the correct URL from your repo in GitHub.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/[username]/[reponame].git
```

You need to add you existing files to your local commit:

```
git add .   # this adds all the files
```

Then you need to make an initial commit, so you do:

```
git commit -a -m "Initial commit" # this stages your files locally for commit. 
                                  # they haven't actually been pushed yet
```

Now you've created a commit in your local repo, but not in the remote one. To put it on the remote, you do the second line you posted:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: This answer is very good! The only problem that I had was that before `git commit -a -m "Initial commit"` I needed to first do a `git pull https://github.com/[username]/[reponame].git` Not sure if the problem was something I did wrong or not, but it worked after that.

Comment: I believe you will also need to click 'share project -> git -> repo' in eclipse

Comment: @Jokab but my local eclipse workspace in ~2 gb, how to stop it from uploading .metadata and other unnecessary files. Add all adds everything.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: @TheDude You'll have to pull first if the repo isn't new. If it's a brand new (with no files) git repo then the above will work.

Comment: `git push --set-upstream origin master` worked for me, as the final step was failing with: fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.

Answer (score 47):

Here is a step by step video of uploading eclipse projects to github

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH4OqYHoHC0

Adding the Steps here.

1. Right click on your eclipse project -> Team -> Share project
2. Choose git from the list shown; check the box asking create or use repository -> click on create repository and click finish. - This will create a local git repo. (Assuming you already have git installed )
3. Right click on project -> Team -> Commit - Select only the files you want to  commit and click on Commit. - Now the files are committed to your local repo.
4. Go to git repositories view in eclipse ( or Team -> Show in repositories View)
5. Expand the git repo of your project and Right click on Remotes -> Create Remote
6. Remote name will appear as origin, select 'Configure Push' Option and click ok
7. In the next dialog, click on change next to URI textbox and give your git url, username, password and click on 'Save and Push'. This configures git Push.
8. For configuring Fetch, go to Git Repositories -> Remote -> Configure Fetch -> Add -> Master Branch -> Next -> Finish -> Save and Fetch
9. For configuring Master Branch, Branch -> Local -> Master Branch -> Right click and configure branch -> Remote: origin and Upstream Branch : refs/heads/master -> click ok

On refreshing your repo, you will be able to see the files you committed and you can do push and pull from repo.

Comment: Before step 7 you need to create an empty project on Github.

Answer (score 2):

You need a git client to upload your project to git servers. For eclipse [EGIT](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) is a nice plugin to use GIT.

to learn the basic of git  , see [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html) // i think you should have the basic first

Answer (score 1):

For  eclipse i  think EGIT is the best option.
This guide  http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html will help you understand git quick.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these answers mention how to share the project on Git, which is easy, you just share the code on git, but one thing to take note of is that there is no apparent "project file" that the end user can double click on. Instead you have to use Import->General->Existing project and select the whole folder

Answer (score 0):

Jokab's answer helped me a lot but in my case I could not push to github until I logged in my github account to my git bash so i ran the following commands

`git config credential.helper store`

then

`git push http://github.com/[user name]/[repo name].git`

After the second command a GUI window appeared, I provided my login credentials and it worked for me.