# Eclipse, Egit, Github: remove pushed project folder

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have successfully created a git hub repository, a local master, committed the initial changes and pushed them to github.

Unfortunately the project folder from Eclipse ends up in the repository. For example:

```
<username>/<gitrepositoryname>/<eclipse project folder>/<project files & README>
```

when for most people it looks like:

```
<username>/<gitrepositoryname>/<project files & README>
```

I created a new local master after I found this tutorial [Push eclipse project to GitHub with EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654719/push-eclipse-project-to-github-with-egit)

but now I am running into push problems such as  "HEAD rejected - non-fast-forward" when using the new local master.

Can some please help me to correct this locally/remotely? Is there a way to switch local master branches so that I can sync the correct one with githib?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to fix:

1. Go to the "workspace" where you keep `<eclipse project folder>`
2. Make sure to delete the `.git` folder there
3. Tell git to force push the changes. (Checkbox) (*It's usually not good to force git to do something, because you could loose commits/data **BUT** here, we really want to overwrite the old repository with the new one.*)

[image: Eclipse git push dialog]

4. Your changes should be up immediately. **Next time you push, please make sure, the force push checkbox is disabled again**