# How to connect local project to github repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have java project using Eclipse. I created an account and repository in github and try to synchronise this repo with my project. But when i try to add or clone the rpo in gitHub desktop app it doesn't see my project structure. what should i do?

Comment: Did you commit and push the files to your repo?

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654719/push-eclipse-project-to-github-with-egit

Comment: @AndrewLi i tried. but there were nothing to commit.

Answer (score 2):

Once you created the repository on github, you have to add that remote into your repository.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY
```

after that, you can

```
git push origin master
```

and see that your project is now updated

Comment: it gave the error: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any error messages?

It should be pretty straightforward using the command line. From the directory where you want to clone the repo,

`git clone http://repo-url.git` should take care of it.