# Egit plugin configuration for pushing the existing project

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am stuck here:

[image: here]

Can anyone guide me how to go further to push my maven project into the git hub repository I have already created.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654719/push-eclipse-project-to-github-with-egit)

Comment: Have you read https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on project, select team, share project. On Configure Git Repository screen, use the drop down on Repository to select the one you created earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot mike i successfully did commit and push my project .

Comment: @raje Good work, welcome to stack overflow, remember to use the feedback buttons to reward everyone contributing helpful answers and comments

Comment: @raje did this answer your question?

Comment: @raje thanks for letting us know. Please click the tick symbol for the answer if it answered your question.